# Java - MigLayout seting bounds

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, miglayout

so i have a problem i cant solve i want my GUI app to be split between 3 JPanels (left, center, right). I want left panel and right panel to be of fixed size and center to be fluid. Meaning side panels expand only vertically as JFrame is expanded and center panel expands bot horizontally and vertically.

I have set minimal size for all panels to be height of 600 but they just stay in the minimal size and dont expand as JForm increases i dont know how to set bounds to JFrame borders so they expand whit it.

```
package ppe.view;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class UI_View extends JFrame
{
    private JList       browse  = new JList();
    private JScrollPane rightX   = new JScrollPane();
    private JButton     btn1    = new JButton("Button 1");
    private JButton     btn2    = new JButton("Button 2");
    private JButton     btn3    = new JButton("Button 3");
    private JButton     btn4    = new JButton("Button 4");


    public UI_View()
    {
        this.setTitle("Prototype MVC Arhitecture");
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        this.setExtendedState(this.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(new MigLayout());

        JPanel content = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
        content.setBackground(Color.black);

        JPanel right  = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
        JPanel center = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
        JPanel left   = new JPanel(new MigLayout());

        right.setBackground(Color.red);
        right.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 600));
        right.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 37500));

        center.setBackground(Color.green);
        center.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 600));

        left.setBackground(Color.blue);
        left.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 600));
        left.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 37500));

        content.add(left);
        content.add(center);
        content.add(right);

        this.setContentPane(content);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new UI_View().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

I have tryed bounding them to another content panel and adding that panel as ContentPane to JFrame that automatically bounds it to JFrame border but the thing is still pretty much fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `MiGLayout` why don't you configure the constraints when adding the components?

This, for example, might help (although I'm a `MiGLayout` beginner, too):

```
 content.add(left, "growy");
 content.add(center, "grow"); //the same as growx, growy
 content.add(right, "growy");
```

In some cases I needed to also add a `pushx` but I'm not sure when this is needed. Please refer to the documentation for further information.

*Edit*: it seems like you always have to add `push` for components that should cause the column/row to grow. Otherwise `grow` alone would make the components as big as the column/row they are in which in turn is defined by the largest component in that column/row. If there is more space available columns/rows won't grow to fill it without the `push` keyword.

From the documentation:

> Components will never "push" the column/row's size to be larger using the grow keyword.

Comment: Thanks for help i did look in to grow constraints but they dont seem to help.

Comment: @kellax, try to create your `MiGLayout` with the `"debug"` parameter to see the borders painted. Additionally, try adding `"grow, pushx"` for the center panel.

Comment: Wow it works now left and right are fixed size and center. I had to define it like this: for side panels .add(panel, "growy, pushy") and for center "grow, pushx"

Not fully sure but i think "psuhx or pushy" serve as extra parameter in to which direction to expand if u want to fully fill up the space.

Comment: @kellax yes, I was about look it up but I assume `push` means that any components to the right or bottom are pushed away while growing. Without it, only the rightmost or bottom components seem to grow.